# IBM BPM EPV new line

Tags: business-process-management

I'm using EPV to store some text which will end up in a file.

I want to store carriage return and new line but, when I enter **\r\n** to "Default Value" box, I get string which contains characters \,r,\ and n.

Is there a way which I can enter carriage return and new line as EPV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did eventually was entering **%0D%0A** to Default Value box and I've used method *decodeURIComponent* in Server Script component where I actually use that value.